# What is this plant with dark leaves and a red flower?

Tags: identification, canna

Can you name this plant which has quite dark leaves and a red flower:

[image: Unknown plant]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a [**canna** ("canna lily")](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canna_(plant)), a group pf plants native to the Americas.

With it's large decorative leaves and spectacular blooms, it's been target of much breeding and cultivation, so today there are many different cultivars and hybrids on the market, your specimen with the red foliage being one of them.

Comment: Many varieties: https://www.google.com/search?q=canna&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMImcivt86yxwIVEAmSCh1kXgkb&biw=753&bih=398